# Using QGIS on local network?

Tags: qgis, qgis-server

I would like to host QGIS on a server so that people can browse my maps. Is this possible to do completely on a local network as some of the data is sensitive and cannot be uploaded online. Looking for something with the look and feel of ESRI's webapp builder via Portal/Enterprise.

Is this something that is possible/exists?

Comment: Hi, and welcome to GIS SE! If you haven't yet, please be sure to take the [tour] to get familiar with the question/answer model we follow here. Generally, "is X possible" questions can be answered with a simple "Yes". In order to get the most out of this community, try to make your question as detailed and focused as possible, and always include information about what you've already tried or researched.

Answer (score 1):

you can easily host your data and maps with qgis server or geoserver. If more functions are required you can use geonode.

Comment: And when it comes to limiting the access to local network that's why firewalls exist.